# Retrieve value from usercontrol in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have added a calendar user control in a template field within a grid view. I want to save the data from the row. I need to get the date  from the user control that the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

So you will have some control which will fire some RowCommand event and in that you will have e.Item.FindControl('calendar-control-id') to get the calendar.